# Getting error in coding PHP

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to display username for a certain time and I wrote also in PHP. But it is showing error. Please help me to fix error:

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    if(time() <= strtotime("2012-11-10")) {
        $link=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username) ;
        mysql_select_db($db_name,$link) ;
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbluser");
        while($v = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $username = $v['username'];
            echo("<center><table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#111111' width='343' id='AutoNumber1'>");
            echo("<tr><td><b>UserName</b></td>");
            echo("</tr>");
            echo("<tr><td>$username</td>");
            echo("</td></tr></table>");
        }
    else
        echo 'testing period dated ended';
    }
?>
```

Comment: What error! Do mention that.

Comment: Could you give us the error please?

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: No, please, don't tell us. We love cliffhangers.

Comment: @deceze This way is more of a challenge

Answer (score 2):

```
$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username, /* PASSWORD HERE */);
```

You need to assign a password for the [**mysql connection**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Comment: I've replaced your mentioned line with 
$link=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username, $db_password);
but it still showing error

Comment: @Атанас That shouldn't throw an error, I think. It is an optional parameter and uses `mysql.default_password` in the php.ini if not specified.

Comment: @user Now you're just trolling, right? **What error?!**

Answer (score 1):

You were missing curly brackets AND the third parameter for mysql_connect:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if(time() <= strtotime("2012-11-10")) {
    $link=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$password) ;
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link) ;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbluser");
    while($v = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $username = $v['username'];
        echo("<center><table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#111111' width='343' id='AutoNumber1'>");
        echo("<tr><td><b>UserName</b></td>");
        echo("</tr>");
        echo("<tr><td>$username</td>");
        echo("</td></tr></table>");
    }
}
else{
    echo 'testing period dated ended';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't use [`mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) functions. They are deprecated. Choose a different API, after reading the guide **[here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)**.

---

Your **If** statement needs its closing brace. Also, the syntax for [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) might need a password, unless you are using `mysql.default_password` in php.ini as the password. (It is empty by default)

```
<?php
...
if(...) { // --> needs its closing brace
    $link=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username) ; // no password?
    ...
    ...
    while(...) {
    ...
    ... 
    } //while closes here WHERE does if close?
else
    ...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if(time() <= strtotime("2012-11-10")) {
    $link=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$password) ;
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link) ;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbluser");
    while($v = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $username = $v['username'];
        echo("<center><table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#111111' width='343' id='AutoNumber1'>");
        echo("<tr><td><b>UserName</b></td>");
        echo("</tr>");
        echo("<tr><td>$username</td>");
        echo("</td></tr></table>");
    }

}
else
    echo 'testing period dated ended';
```

Answer (score 0):

First pass third parameter to mysql_connect(), that is password.

Second:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if(time() <= strtotime("2012-11-10")) {
$link=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username) ;
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link) ;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbluser");
while($v = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$username = $v['username'];
echo("<center><table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#111111' width='343' id='AutoNumber1'>");
echo("<tr><td><b>UserName</b></td>");
echo("</tr>");
echo("<tr><td>$username</td>");
echo("</td></tr></table>");
 }
}
else {
echo 'testing period dated ended';
}
?>
```

Nesting was not proper